# owl carousel navigation hide

Tags: css, owl-carousel

I use owl carousel and I want the navigation above the slide in order to navigate easily. Now they are hidden or below the slider. I don't know how to put them above. I tried z-index in the `CSS` for the carousel and navigation but nothing happens. Need help thank you !

JS

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
        navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        items : 1,
        itemsDesktop : false,
        itemsDesktopSmall : false,
        itemsTablet: false,
        itemsMobile : false
        });

  });
</script>
```

CSS

```
    #owl-demo2 .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    .owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2000;
    *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
    margin: 90px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #869791;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);/*IE7 fix*/
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.owl-buttons {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -45px !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translateX(-50%)!important;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a working demo on JSfiddle?

Comment: i can put all my code on jsfiddle but the example is here [link](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html) i hope it's enought for you thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` doesn't put items like you wish it would. I think you need to change positions of these buttons rather than setting different `z-index`.

Here you have an example of how `z-index` work. Change `z-index` as you wish and check how the alignement work on these boxes:

https://jsfiddle.net/grmcfb7z/

You can try this CSS for your solution:

```
.owl-buttons{
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

You might want to tweak it if it doesn't look as you wish. I tried it on your example from the comments and it looks great to me.

**UPDATE**

After digging into the exact problem, here is the full solution:

```
#owl-demo2 .item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; //we don't need position or z-index property here
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline; /*IE7 life-saver */
    margin: 10px; //fixed margin to not mess our buttons alignement
    padding: 5px 15px; //smaller padding for better look
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #869791;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=50); /*IE7 fix*/
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.owl-buttons, .owl-pagination {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translateX(-50%) !important; //here we override our buttons
                                            //positions
}

.owl-buttons {
    top: 0 !important; //nav position
}

.owl-pagination {
    bottom: 0 !important; //pagination position
}
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43wo7g98/3/

Comment: i tried your solution but nothing happens the navigation is still under or below the slideshow. I reduce my picture but i don't see navigation either

Comment: When you override `.owl-buttons` does it appear in the inspector? Maybe you just have to use `!important` to force the changes?

Comment: yes it appears but nothing happens i had in my question the code of owl and i try to change zoom: 1 by zoom:4 i see only one button the prev button. but i don't see the navigation (little dot) and the next button. it's weird because i put already one owl carousel in my index and already work fine

Comment: Could you remove `position: fixed;` from `.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div` ?

Comment: It would be great if you try to make a jsfiddle. It's really hard to guess what's wrong without 'seeing' actual problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/43wo7g98/ i do that but i can put pictures. Is this ok for you ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/43wo7g98/1/ check if thats what you want. I set owl container width to 50% just to see how it looks, if you need to tweak it to look different feel free to what to change. Basically i changed buttons padding and margin and i set some `margin-top` to make space for these buttons

Comment: And by the way. Always remember to add all the needed components to jsfiddle like jquery and owl-carousel in your case. You can do it by adding CDN links on the left side of jsfiddle :)

Comment: yes ok thank you but i need button on the picture not outside in fact

Comment: Just set `top` property to 0, like that: https://jsfiddle.net/43wo7g98/2/ and if you want to put pagination controls on your image as well, make `owl-pagination` the same as `owl-buttons` styles, just replace `top` property with `bottom = 0;`

Comment: You'r welcome. I'll update my solution to fit your problem.

Comment: do you have an ideat to put any slider with video which work perfectly ?

Comment: You can use owl carousel for that as well, just set up `video: true` in your plugin options.